# Dynamically create a zod schema based on a remote config

Tags: typescript, zod

I've been having more trouble than I thought creating form validation for a dynamic form using zod. The form lives on multiple domains and depending on the domain, a different configuration is fetched from a remote server. It might look like this:

```js
  signupForm: {
    fields: {
      birthdate: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      newsletter: {
        enabled: false,
      }
  }
```

Based on the enabled property, I want to expand the schema.

Initially I thought something like this might work:

```js
  const baseScheme = z.object({
    firstname: z.string({ required_error: "Please enter a first name" }),
    lastname: z.string({ required_error: "Please enter a first name" }),
    email: z
      .string({ required_error: "Please enter an email address" })
      .email({ message: "Invalid email address" }),
  });

  const newsletterSchema = z.object({
    newsletter: z.boolean().optional(),
  });

  let scheme = baseScheme;

  if (config.signupForm.fields.newsletter.enabled) // The config object is fetched from a remote source, so not static
    scheme = scheme.merge(newsletterSchema);
```

However, the typing for scheme remains the base scheme

```js
let scheme: z.ZodObject<{
    firstname: z.ZodString;
    lastname: z.ZodString;
    email: z.ZodString;
}>
```

The other way around results in the same type

```js
  let scheme = z.object({}).merge(baseScheme);

  if (config.signupForm.fields.newsletter.enabled)
    scheme = newsletterSchema.merge(scheme);
```

It seems like either zod or TypeScript can't infer the conditional type from .merge because as soon as I assign it to a new variable, it works:

```js
  let scheme = baseScheme;

  if (config.signupForm.fields.newsletter.enabled) 
    const newScheme = scheme.merge(newsletterSchema);
```

```js
  const newScheme: z.ZodObject<{
      firstname: z.ZodString;
      lastname: z.ZodString;
      email: z.ZodString;
      newsletter: z.ZodOptional<z.ZodBoolean>;
  }>
```

Any ideas how I could keep the typesafety? My current approach that kind of works looks like this:

```js
  type FinalFormType = typeof baseScheme &
    Partial<
      typeof newsletterSchema & typeof legalSchema & typeof birthdateSchema
    >;

  return scheme as unknown as FinalFormType;
```

Which is obviously not ideal and error-prone as you have to manually update the FinalFormType

Comment: What type do you expect for `scheme`?

Comment: Try `const scheme = config.signupForm.fields.newsletter.enabled ? baseScheme.merge(newsletterSchema) : baseScheme;`, not `let scheme` with conditional assignmets.

Comment: @Bergi scheme in this example should look like newScheme. Your ternary example would work in this one case, but as you can see in the config I have multiple fields that could conditionally be added to the scheme, not just newsletter, so that wouldn't work in my case unfortunately